# If the checkbox in the datagridview is checked, it will save to database and if not it will just prompt to select a row

Tags: c#, mysql

this is my code but it always prompt if you want to add the rows even if it is not checked. what do you think is the problem?

```
 private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = 
        (from row in dg_students.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() 
              where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true
              select row).ToList();         

        if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Are you sure you want to add this student?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
                {
                    try
                    {


                        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
                         string Query = "Insert into southpoint_school.classlist(schoolYear, yearLevel, sectionName, studentID, studentName, gender) values ('" + schoolyr + "','" + cmb_level.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "')";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Your message box will always show because you didn't put a condition on your if statement

Comment: You could put an if statement around your current one to check if the rows are checked

Comment: sorry but condition is always true. i forgot to put. so it always select the rows.

Comment: { List selectedRows = (from row in dg_students.Rows.Cast() where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true select row).ToList();

Comment: what does the quickwatch show when you step evaluate this 
`selectedRows `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an **if** statement around your current if statement, that checks the number of selected rows:

```
if(selectedRows.Count >= 1)
{
    //Your if statement to run with the selected rows
}
else
{
    //Prompt user to select a row
{
```

Comment: still not working. But I think there is something wrong with this code :   List selectedRows = (from row in dg_students.Rows.Cast() where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true select row).ToList();

Comment: Yes but everytime I click the add button, it will always prompt  "Are you sure you want to add this student?" even if no rows are checked.

Comment: You have to wrap your message box if statement in another if statement